# Window open on the Middle of the Right edge of the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I have the following code. I'm trying to make the window open on the right side of the primary screen, midway down the side of the screen. It's not moving the starting location of the window at all.

```
int screenWidth = (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
int screenHeight = (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
cd.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (cd.Height / 2);
cd.Left = screenWidth - (cd.Width + 4);
```

Comment: As I understand "cd" is your Window instance?
If you are placeing your code in MainWindow class you, simply use
this.Top and this.Left instead of creating an instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your code in ***Load*** event of the window, also this code is a bit more readeable, and works as you wanted to, I checked it.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
        this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
        this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Top + this.Height;
}
```